# Is Collection really stronger than Replacement?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

The two powerhouse schemata of set theory are Replacement and Collection:

> **Replacement.** For every definable function $f$ and every set $x$, $f"x$ is a set.
>
> **Collection.** For every definable relation $R$ and every set $x$, there is a set $y$ such that for every $u\in x$ there is $v\in y$ such that $u\mathrel{R}v$.

Easily, Collection implies Replacement, and assuming $\sf ZF$ we can prove the converse as well. If we omit the Power Set axiom, then the reverse implication no longer holds, and Collection is a strictly stronger schema than Replacement.

But since $\sf ZF$ without Power Set is strictly weaker, consistency-wise, than $\sf ZF$ itself, it raises the following question:

> Does $\sf\operatorname{Con}(ZF(C)-)\to\operatorname{Con}(ZF(C)^-)$?

(Here $\sf ZF-$ is $\sf ZF$ without Power Set, but with Replacement, and $\sf ZF^-$ is the same theory with Replacement replaced by Collection. The C stands for the Well-Ordering Theorem.)

Comment: You've defined ZF- twice, and ZF^- not at all.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Well, before the edit, anyway :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The theories are equiconsistent and have the same strength as second order arithmetic $\text{Z}_2$.  Since we have an $L$-definable well-ordering of the constructible universe $L$, replacement implies collection and ZFC\P in $L$.

Comment: Do we also have the consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC^-}$ with the reflection principle (in the form $\phi(a)\to \exists M\ni a \phi^M(a)$) since $L$ satisfies it?

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes, we do.